# Paid $4.26 on a $133 transfer - why unconfirmed?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I sent money to myself from a Bitpay wallet (using send Max) to a Cashapp wallet.

Transaction id -  577b3fe1e372e2375bcfbb2c666cdc74fa766fd022592040a539154c9ff7d820
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/577b3fe1e372e2375bcfbb2c666cdc74fa766fd022592040a539154c9ff7d820

Why 20 hours unconfirmed and is there any way to get this unstuck considering the 2 web wallets I use?

Answer (score 2):

I'm predicting that this transaction will confirm in less than a week considering its relative feerate.

> Paid $4.26 on a $133 transfer - why unconfirmed?

Because the input addresses are `1...` addresses instead of the newer SegWit addresses `bc1`. By switching to a native SegWit addresses you may enjoy faster confirmation times at any constant feerate level.

The destination address is `3...` which means probably it's a SegWit address too. However, `3...` addresses pay slightly higher fees than `bc1` addresses so `bc1` addresses are suggested whenever possible. (Still, the suggested feerate difference between `1...` and `3...` addresses will make a considerable difference, you'll notice it when you spend from your destination address)